# Uploading images using the csv

Tags: magento-1.9

I have exported my data with my products and filled in all the info with the location to the images located in the media folder. I am using the same image for multiple products, could that be a problem?

Comment: Your question is not much clear. Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: I have a bunch of images uploaded in my media folder. I am editing the exported csv to show the path of the images needed for each simple product. When I import the csv back, none of the images show or appear on the products in the backend. I get no errors.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the detail in there instead of creating comments. This will make it easier for others to help you and you are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using the same image for multiple products is no problem. I have done it before. Are you receiving an error message when trying to upload, or are the images just not showing up? Are you using the steps outlined here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/importing-product-images ?

Comment: I am using 1.9 instead of magento go. This is kind of different but I have used a similar method.

Comment: Also no errors or anything.

Comment: I thought I had used those instructions with Enterprise, but I uploaded images manually instead of through an archive file. Are you receiving an error message when trying to import your images? When I did this, I found that using the full path to the images worked best. For example, if I put them in /tmp/magento/import, I would insert /tmp/magento/import/example.jpg into the CSV. If I uploaded them to Magento's media/import directory, I would use /var/www/example.com/htdocs/media/import/example.jpg.

Comment: If no errors, then when you export the csv, add the image filenames, import it back, then re-export the data, what shows up in the image path fields?

Comment: When I export again it comes back as blank in the areas I had filled in

Comment: What path on the server are you using to store the images, and what path are you entering into the CSV?

Comment: I am using the default theme and am uploading the first image of a tshirt through the back end and then exporting the csv and copy and pasting the img path from the first product to the others.

Comment: It's very possible that, if you are just copying and pasting, Magento is looking in the wrong directory for your product image(s). I will have to check on the specifics of 1.9, but Magento should be looking in your media/import directory for the file you named. It sounds like you haven't put a file there for it to find.

Comment: Magento is putting the image in /k/5/k500_banana_model_front_072014.jpg
 which is in the media/catalog directory

Comment: Try to copy that file to media/import and refer to it as /k500_banana_model_front_072014.jpg in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Nothing. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I have anything more to offer here. I went back to look at my successful import, and I had all the images in media/import/img and in the spreadsheet I used the path /img/image.png